# Return value being passed as an argument

Tags: c++

I come from a java background but am now working on large C++ code bases.  I often see this pattern:

```
void function(int value, int& result);
```

And above method is called like so:

```
int result = 0;
function(42, result);
std::cout << "Result is " << result << std::endl;
```

In java, the following would be more common:

```
int result = function(42);
```

Although the above is perfectly possible in C++, how come the former appears more common (in the codebase I'm working on at least)?  Is it stylistic or something more?

Comment: The function `void function(int value, int result);` will not modify the passed `result`.

Comment: I edited that, hope it's ok. I believe this is the pattern OP refers to.

Comment: Typo, apologies.  Thanks for updating @lubgr

Comment: "how come the former appears more common?" what evidence do you have for that claim? I don't know the numbers, but I would expect that out-parameters are far less common than "normal" return values. Iirc C++ core guidelines also recommend against out-parameters

Comment: `am now working on large C++ code bases` `how come the former appears more common?` is it more common _in that code base_? Why not ask the author? What code base is that?

Comment: Any answer will be opinion-based, and specific to your code base. In general, it's just one way to use functions in C++. Some people hate this pattern, some people love it, most are somewhere in the middle.

Comment: It is more common in that code base, because the author likes to write overcomplicated code. That's it.

Comment: In C++ code bases that were converted from Pascal, the use of an out parameter for a class or struct is used because it follows the constraints of older Pascal.  Only in such code bases (which haven't been refactored to not do that, yet) have I seen that out-parameter C++ coding practice prevalent.  I work in such a code base.  Not a fan; zero stars, would not recommend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, this used to be an established technique to have more than one output of a function. E.g. in this signature,

```
int computeNumberButMightFail(int& error_code);
```

you would have both the payload `int` as the return value, and a reference to some error variable that is set from within the function to signal an error. It is clear these days that there are better techniques, e.g. `std::optional<T>` is a good return value, there might be a more flexible `std::expected<T, ...>`, and with newer C++ standards, we can return multiple values with `std::make_tuple` and destructure them at the call side with structured bindings. For exceptional error scenarios, the usual approach is to use... well... exceptions.

Second, this is an optimization technique from the days in which (N)RVO wasn't widely available: if the output of a function is an object that is expensive to copy, you wanted to make sure no unnecessary copies are made:

```
void fillThisHugeBuffer(std::vector<LargeType>& output);
```

means we pass a reference to the data in order to avoid an unnessecary copy when returning it by value. However, this is outdated, too, and returning large objects by value is usually considered the more idiomatic approach, because C++17 guarantees something called materialization of temporaries and (name) return value optimization is implemented by all major compilers.

See also the core guidelines:
[F.20](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-out) - "For “out” output values, prefer return values to output parameters".

Answer (score 1):

Modifiable parameters that receive values as a side effect of a function call are called *out* parameters.  They are generally accepted as a bit archaic, and have fallen somewhat out of fashion as better techniques are available in C++.  As you suggested, returning computed values from functions is the ideal.

But real-world constraints sometimes drive people toward out parameters:

1. returning objects by value is too expensive due to the cost of copying large objects or those with non-trivial copy constructors
2. returning multiple values, and creating a tuple or struct to contain them is awkward, expensive, or not possible.
3. When objects *cannot* be copied (possible private or deleted copy constructor) but must be created "in place"

Most of these issues face legacy code, because C++11 gained "move semantics" and C++17 gained "guaranteed copy elision" which obviate most of these cases.

In any new code, it's usually considered bad style or a *code smell* to use out parameters, and most likely an acquired habit that carried over from the past (when this was a more relevant technique.)  It's not wrong, but one of those things we try to avoid if it's not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know, this case is not common in C++ at least not with primitive data types as return values. There are a few cases to consider:

1. If you working with plain C or in a very restricted context, where C++ exceptions are not allowed (like realtime applications). Then the return value of a function is often used to indicate the success of a function. An in C could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int func(int arg, int* res) {
  if(arg > 10) {
    return EINVAL; //this is an error code from errnoe
  }
  
  ... //do stuff
  *res = my_result;
}
```

This is sometimes used in C++ as well and so the result must by assigned by reference/pointer.

2. When your result is struct or object which exists before the call of your function and the purpose of your function is to modify attributes inside the struct or object. This is a common pattern because you have to pass the argument by reference (to avoid a copy) anyway. So it is not necessary to return the same object as you pass to the function. An example in C++ could be:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Point {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
};

void fill_point(Point& p, int x, int y) {
   p.x = x;
   p.y = y;
}

int main() {
  Point p();
  fill_point(p);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, this is a trivial and there are better solutions like defining the fill-function as a method in the object. But sometimes with regard to the single-responsible paradigm of objects this pattern is common under more complex circumstances.

3. In Java you can't control your heap. Every object you define is on the heap and automatically passed by reference to a function. In C++ you have the choice where you wan't your object stored (heap or stack) and how to pass the object to a function. It is important to keep in mind that a pass by value of an object copies it and returning an object from a function by value also copies the object. For returning an object by reference you have to ensure that its lifecycle exceeds the scope of your function by placing it on the heap or by passing it to the function by reference.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why an out parameter might be used in a C++ codebase.

For example:

- You have multiple outputs:

  `void compute(int a, int b, int &x, int &y) { x=a+b; y=a-b; }`
- You need the return value for something else: For example, in PEG parsing you might find something like this:

  `if (parseSymbol(pos,symbolName) && parseToken(pos,"=") && parseExpression(pos,exprNode)) {...}`

where the parse functions look like

```
bool parseSymbol(int &pos, string &symbolName); 
bool parseToken(int &pos, const char *token);
```

and so on.

- To avoid object copies.
- Programmer didn't knew better.

But basically I think, any answer is opinion based, because it's matter of style and coding policies if and how out-parameters are used or not.